# OpenSearch: vm.max_map_count is set, but still get error: vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mmap, opensearch

I am trying to install OpenSearch on Ubuntu 22.04 using Docker, but on startup of the Docker container, I get:

> vm.max_map_count is set, but still get error: vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

However, I have done the following:

- Added "vm.max_map_count=262144" to /etc/sysctl.conf
- Run sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144 using sudo
- Run sysctl -p using sudo
- Run "sysctl vm.max_map_count" using sudo to which I get a response: "vm.max_map_count = 262144
  "

Why doesn't OpenSearch detect that I have set vm.max_map_count and where is it getting its value from?

## Edit

Here is my opensearch.yaml that I am using with docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1: # This is also the hostname of the container within the Docker network (i.e. https://opensearch-node1/)
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest # Specifying the latest available image - modify if you want a specific version
    container_name: opensearch-library
    environment:
      - cluster.name=library # Name the cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-library-node1 # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-library-node1 # Nodes to look for when discovering the cluster
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-library-node1 # Nodes eligible to serve as cluster manager
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # Set min and max JVM heap sizes to at least 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1 # Set memlock to unlimited (no soft or hard limit)
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # Maximum number of open files for the opensearch user - set to at least 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-library-data1:/home/martin/sixteenTB/librarysearch # Creates volume called opensearch-data1 and mounts it to the container
    ports:
      - 9200:9200 # REST API
      - 9600:9600 # Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net # All of the containers will join the same Docker bridge network
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest # Make sure the version of opensearch-dashboards matches the version of opensearch installed on other nodes
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601 # Map host port 5601 to container port 5601
    expose:
      - "5601" # Expose port 5601 for web access to OpenSearch Dashboards
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200"]' # Define the OpenSearch nodes that OpenSearch Dashboards will query
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-library-data1:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

## Edit 2

I realise that I am running Docker Desktop. Does this mean that each of my containers is running a separate VM? How do I configure this kernel param within their VMs?

Comment: Yep - doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I have added the configuration file above. This error happens shortly after I try to start OpenSearch using docker-compose

Comment: Really? The install docs say it shouldn't run in node mode when vm.max_map_count is below 262144 -- and my attempt to start it seems to confirm that... Except so far as I can see, I have set it.

Comment: I suggest you reboot Ubuntu, verify `sysctl vm.max_map_count`, then run `docker-compose up`.